# Why do I need parentheses here?

Tags: scala

Why do I need parentheses around x:Int in this case:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).filter((x:Int) => x > 3)
```

but not x in this case:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).filter(x => x > 3)
```

If I try:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).filter(x:Int => x > 3)
```

I get:

```
identifier expected but integer literal found
```

What exactly does that mean?

Comment: I've tried second case and it works fine on scala version 2.9.1

Comment: Both work. dublintech is just asking why it won't compile in the first version if you omit the parenthesese for the parameter list

Comment: @Girafik I have made question clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parentheses show where the parameter's type ends.  Since the `=>` symbol is valid in scala types (indicating a function type), just having the `=>` there doesn't mean that the type is over.  Consider this:

```
List(Map(1->2)).filter((x: Int => Int) => x(1) == 2)
```

The parentheses clearly show that the first `=>` is part of the type of `x` and the second is defining the function.

In your second example, there is no type on `x`, so there's no ambiguity about the role of the `=>`.

Comment: Good rationale. Just a nitpick, there is no "type ascription" here, only the parameter type.

Comment: @dhg I don't see how the brackets on x:Int in List(1,2,3,4,5).filter((x:Int) => x > 3) prevent any ambiguity.  I have updated question perhaps my question is clearer noe.

Answer (score 1):

`x: Int => Int` - x is function of type `Int => Int`

`(x:Int) => ...` -  x is function parameter

Comment: But would you evere have x: Int => Int in a function literal? Can you give example?

Comment: val inc = (x:Int) => x + 1